# HowTo print with Qt5 without driver (PostScript / PCL)

Tags: c++, printing, qt5, printer-control-language

I'm developing a application that should run on an embedded device. The app should be able to communicate with different printers, without deploying a driver for each.

That's why I figured out, that PostScript or PCL are good options for me.

Since Qt5 does not support PCL or PostScript, I would like to use another library for my exports but wasn't able to find a single library till now. I would also like to know, if there are other standards like PCL or PostScript to use a printer without installing a driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt supports CUPS which sports a flexible driver architecture and supports PostScript, PCL and PDF printers, and many more.

Comment: Thanks! That was what I'm looking for. I'm hoping, that all of my printers are supported!